# How to get name of last folder found using `find`

Tags: bash

I have a folder structure containing multiple components:

```
src-/
    |-components-/
                 |-componentA
                 |-componentB
                 |-componentC
```

I want to find each component folder, execute a command on it, and use the folder name as the name of the each output folder inside my `dist/` directory. So it should look like this:

```
dist-/
     |-componentA
     |-componentB
     |-componentC
```

Currently I'm running the following command:

`BABEL_ENV=cjs find src/components/** -type d -exec babel {} --out-dir dist/{} \;`

However this gives me the full file path inside `{}`, so the result is as follows:

`src/components/componentA/index.js -> dist/src/components/componentA/index.js`

I would like the result to be:

`src/components/componentA/index.js -> dist/componentA/index.js`

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
while read -r -d "" path; do
    basename=${path##*/}    # will remove "src/components/" portion
    BABEL_ENV=cjs babel "$path" --out-dir "dist/$basename"
done < <(find src/components/* -type d -print0)
```

It transfers the output of `find` to the `while` loop in which the path name is modified to meet your requirement.